# ¿Cómo instalo mongodb en virtualenv?

Tags: python, mongodb, virtualenv

soy novato en el mundo de la programación y poco a poco voy aprendiendo, espero me ayuden..

estoy creando una aplicación de escritorio con Python, y quiero instalar Mondo DB y utilizarlo dentro de Virtual Env y no encuentro la manera de como hacer eso, he intentado colocando pip install mongo y pip install pymongo, pero al ejecutar algún script de conexión me da error, agradecería me ayudaran a instalarlo paso a paso que creo que no son muchos

este es el error al intentar conectarme

```
raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(Topology Description:
 <TopologyDescription id: 610584832aed63ebe4d22ea0, 
 topology_type: Single, 
 servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown,
 rtt: None, 
 error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] 
No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión')>]>
```

este es un breve código que tengo para probar que funciona

````
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost',port=27017)
db = client['prueba']
coleccion = db['trades']
coleccion.insert_one({"nombre": "aaaaa", "apellido": "bbbbbb"})```
````

Comment: 1. Asegúrate de estar dentro del entorno virtual y tenerlo activado 2. Qué error te da?

Comment: he intentado dentro y fuera del entorno virtual, el error es básicamente que excede el tiempo de conexión, como que no encontrara nada

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con la instalación. Y agrega el error a tu pregunta

Comment: Como haces la conexión? Agrega todo lo que aporte para resolver tu problema

Comment: ¿Puede ser un problema con el firewall de windows? Revisa qué dice la documentación de mongodb sobre la configuración.

Comment: Depronto agregando mongodb al PATH de "variables de entorno". si estas usando windows

Comment: MongoDB es un motor de Base de Datos. Se instala en el Sistema Operativo, no en un entorno virtual. Debes asegurarte que tu servidor está activo y escuchando peticiones en el puerto TCP por defecto, de lo contrario no podrás establecer nunca una conexión al mismo.